# MATLAB: Extracting elements periodically

Tags: matlab

I'd like to extract elements from a vector using the `:`-operator, but periodically. As an example, say `a={1,2,3, ..., 10}` and that I would like to extract elements in steps of 2, changing the reference. Then I would like to get

```
ref 1: 1 3 5 7 9
ref 2: 2 4 6 8 10
ref 3: 3 5 7 9 1
...
```

Is there a keyword in MATLAB to force it to be periodic? Or do I have to apply `circshift` to the array first, and then extract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the index using a modulo operation: `mod(...-1, numel(a))+1`. Those `-1` and `+1` are needed so the resulting index is 1-based (not 0-based).

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]; % vector to be indexed
ref = 3; % first value for index
step = 2; % step for index
ind = mod(ref+(0:step:numel(a)-1)-1,numel(a))+1; % build index
result = a(ind); % apply index
```

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly generate two set of indices: `id1 = 1:2:length(a);` and `id2 = 2:2:length(a);`. Then you could use `circshift` on these indices array to get the desired arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You said a vector, so I'm going to assume you meant `a = [1,2,3, ..., 10]`. If `a` is a cell, use `b = cell2mat(a)` and replace `a` with `b` in the code below.

I think you `circshift` is the best way to do this but you can do it a pretty quickly

```
a = 1:10;
acirc = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) circshift(a', [-n,0]), 0:length(a)-1, 'uni', 0))';
aout = acirc(:, 1:2:end)
```

This makes a matrix of `a`'s with shifts from 0:9. Then it drops every 2nd element. Then if you want a cell array

```
aout = num2cell(aout,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

first concatenate two ranges [1:10] horizontally as indices to be extracted:

```
IDX = [1:10 1:10]
```

then use a function to extract `n` elements started from `begin` separated with `step`:

```
ref = @(begin,step, n) IDX(begin : step : begin+(n * step)-1 );
```

example:

```
ref(1,2,5)
ref(2,2,5)
ref(3,2,5)
ref(4,2,5)
```